# Android openOrCreateDatabase issues with Pre-Lollipop Devices

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-4.4-kitkat

I use the following bit of code to modify a specific database on Lollipop (it works fine, by the way):

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("/data/data/com.myapp.identifier/databases/database.db", null);
```

But for some strange reason, it crashes on Pre-Lollipop devices with the error "Unknown Error: Unable to open database (error 14)". Any insight on how to adjust this to work with pre-lollipop devices would be greatly appreciated. If any additional info (more code) is needed, please let me know and I will provide it.

**EDIT**: Apparently Android KitKat and lower can't modify databases from an onCheckChangedListener(). Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Why are you using the full path?

Comment: Don't use hardcoded paths. Also consider using `SQLiteOpenHelper` for database management.

Comment: @CL. I am using the full path because It crashed when I used "database.db".

Comment: @r3pwn Buddy, how did you got rid of that? I'm getting the same error now.